# Proof verification: a planar graph on $n$ vertices has at most $10^n$ spanning trees.

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification

As stated in the title, we want to show

> If $G$ is a planar graph on $n$ vertices, then $G$ has at most $10^n$ spanning trees.

*Proof attempt.* By a corollary of Euler's formula, we have $e\leq 3n-6$. A spanning tree either contains a particular edge or does not, so there are at most $2^{3n-6}$ spanning trees of $G$. We claim $2^{3n-6}\leq 10^n$ for all $n\geq 3$. The base case is obvious, so suppose there is some $n>3$ satisfying $2^{3n-6}\leq 10^n$. Then $2^{3(n+1)-6}=2^{3n-6}\cdot 2^3 \leq 10^n\cdot 2^3 \leq 10^{n+1}$, where the first inequality holds by the inductive hypothesis. $\blacksquare$

Comment: $$2^{3n-6}\leq 2^{3n} =8^n <10^n$$

Comment: Your proof is correct, though unnecessarily complicated as N.S.'s comment shows.  The essential point though, is that is has fewer than $2^{3n-6}$ spanning trees.

Comment: @N.S. Wow, that is certainly a better argument. I wish I had seen that earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is correct, as pointed out in the comments, but in fact one can get a sharper bound. A spanning tree has $n-1$ edges, which gives a bound of $\binom{3n-6}{n-1}$ spanning trees (still far from sharp, since most subgraphs with $n-1$ edges are neither spanning nor trees), which gives growth like $(\frac{27}{4})^n.$ Note that $\frac{27}4 = 6\frac34.$ It is apparently not known whether we can get this below $6$ - see [Maximum number of spanning trees of a planar graph with a fixed number of edges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2832917/maximum-number-of-spanning-trees-of-a-planar-graph-with-a-fixed-number-of-edges)